# How to get Twitter Bootstrap nav dropdown to push down other elements

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap to design a website of mine and it is working well on nearly every level but I can't get the nav bar to push down all the other elements like it does on the Github example.

Here is what my navbar looks like which nearly matches what the example has.  I can't figure out what's different.

```
<html>
<body>
        <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
          <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="container">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
              <a class="brand" href="/"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/MiZZqIZ.png" alt="logo"></a>
              <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
              <span style="font-size:2em">
                <ul class="nav">

                  <li><a href="/videohandler">Upload</a></li>

                  <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
                </ul>
                </span>               
              </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

<!-- all my code -->

</body>
</html>
```

UPDATE:

This is the [Github example](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/examples/hero.html) I was referring to and if you make the browser smaller it will only show the "brand" element and make the rest of the elements in the dropdown on the far right side.  In the example when it slides down it also pushes the divs below it down the same amount.  This is sliding down on my project but not pushing down the divs below it.  On mine it is just going straight down and covering them up.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have other elements pushed downward when the collapsed menu opens (dropdowns), you have to either replace the class 'navbar-fixed-top' in the first div of your code with the class 'navbar-static-top' or redefine the position property for '.navbar-fixed-top' by adding the following lines in the head-section of your code (after link to 'bootstrap.css'):

```
    <style>
        .navbar-fixed-top{position:relative;}
    </style>
```

Explanation:
The classes '.navbar-fixed-top' & '.navbar-fixed-bottom' have their position property set to 'fixed' in 'bootstrap.css', so they are taken out from the normal flow. You have to overwrite/redefine this setting in order to put these elements in the normal flow and get your content pushed downwards when the menu opens from collapsed state. This can be done by setting the css-property 'position' of the element with '.navbar-fixed-*' class to 'relative' or by replacing '.navbar-fixed-*' with '.navbar-static-*'. (The latters have their position already set to 'relative' in 'bootstrap.css'.)

Answer (score 0):

While it's not incredibly clear what you mean by "push down" in this context, based on the use of navbar-fixed I'm going to guess that you mean it's covering up your content. That's an easy fix--just add some padding to your body element. 60px usually works.

Unless that's not your problem, in which case, A link to a JSFiddle or even to what exactly you're talking about on "the Github example" would be nice.

Comment: Hmm...still hard to say exactly what the problem is given how your HTML seems correct. The only thing I can guess is that for whatever reason your navbar is retaining its fixed property instead of losing it at a certain size--you can confirm that with the element inspector. Possibly you haven't included bootstrap-responsive.css or if you're using a custom download of Bootstrap's Javascript components, you may not have downloaded all of the relevant components.

Answer (score -2):

Bootstrap utilizes a scaffolding system, Using row classes and the span 1-12 are the basis of the structure.

For a generalization on how it works I suggest you look at how the samples on the bootstrap page.

http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/getting-started.html#examples

Comment: Yes I've used it quite extensively but they don't use a row for the navbar in any of the official examples.